# Get slider value using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Im trying to get the returned value from ValueContrast() which are getting its value from slider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.ValueContrast).

But im not able to give the function the needed arguments because Contrast() isnt returning a usable value. How can i retrieve the sliders value from outside the class?

```
def Contrast(self):
    groupBox = QGroupBox("Contrast")
    contrast = QRadioButton("&Activate")

    slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
    slider.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
    slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBothSides)
    slider.setTickInterval(10)
    slider.setSingleStep(100)
    slider.setMinimum(-100)
    slider.setMaximum(100)
    slider.setValue(0)

    contrast.setChecked(True)

    slider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.ValueContrast)

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(contrast)
    vbox.addWidget(slider)
    vbox.addStretch(1)
    groupBox.setLayout(vbox)
    return groupBox



def ValueContrast(self, value):
        return value
```

Comment: haven't got the time to test but something like that:
 slider.valueChanged[int].connect(lambda s:self.ValueContrast(s))

Comment: change `slider` to `self.slider` and use `self.slider.value()` to get the value when you want.

Comment: Forgot to mention, but im trying to access the returned value using class.ValueContrast() but i get an error saying that it needs a value. So if i try class.ValueContrast(1) it is returning the value 1, not the value from slider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.ValueContrast)